# Bootstrap Carousel Captions text not responsive and not able to position in left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
<style>

    html,body{

position: relative;
```

}

```
    .carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
top:113px;
left:150px;
}

     .carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- The slideshow -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">

          <img src="./images/ibm commerce background.png" alt="" width="" height="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3 class="text-left">LOREM / IPSUM</h3>
              <h2 class="text-left">UNIVERSAL
                <br>
                LOREM
              </h2>

              <h3 class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

              </h3>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="./images/ibm commerce.png" alt="" width="" height="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3 class="text-left">THE ALL NEW</h3>
              <h2 class="text-left">LOREM
                <br>
                IPSUM
                <br> 
                DOLOR v9</h2>
              <h3 class="text-left">IS HERE !</h3>
              <h3 class="text-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to bootstrap 4 and I'm facing one particular problem. The carousel-caption in my case is to be displayed on the left side. Well in desktop mode, I have tried absolute positioning and it is displaying well. But when I do responsive mode for mobile it is showing very odd. I have given a screenshot for these.

[image]

So my question is do I have to write media queries for both position and fonts or will bootstrap take care of it. Can anyone please guide me on this or at least show a snippet how it is to be done responsive for all screen sizes. It would be immense help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use position: absolute
You need to make sure that your class has an parents class and it's have property position relative that's how position absolute work

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
top:113px;
left:0;
width:100%;
Text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-item .img-fluid {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Adding the img-fluid class to your carousel might help.

Source: https://bootstrapcreative.com/create-full-width-bootstrap-4-responsive-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Add this, to make your text responsive:

```
.carousel-caption h3{
  font-size: 6vw;
}
.carousel-caption h2{
  font-size :2vw;
}
```

And add this to your `<img class="w-100" src="...">` and it will make your image responsive.